# Data is mixed because of textarea

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, while-loop

For some reason i don't know why  the data entering     is mixed beetween two rows one for the choice ( radio buttons values ) and commentary box ( Textarea) . So i would like to know why and how could i solve this problem. Thank you for the help.  I want to insert the value of the textarea  at each row of my table .
The idea is to generate a textarea according to the numbers of the question of the survey .

The radio button set generator is working alone and takings all values , the wrong part is only when i add a new insert to get textareas values .

```
<?php
$link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
$un = 0;
$kv = 0 ;
$msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";    

if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])){    

    $id = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo4"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo4"] : "";
    $Nom = $_REQUEST["Picolo1"];
    $Prenom = $_REQUEST["Picolo2"];
    $Email = $_REQUEST["Picolo3"];

    if ($id !="" && $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !=""){

        $recherche= "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";            

        mysqli_query($link,$recherche);   

        $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
        $num_results = $result->num_rows;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $Ref =$row["Ref"];
            $Question       =$row["Question"];

            $un++;
            $kv++;

            echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">

            <td>$Question position: $un </td>
            <td>
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"0\">
            </td>
            <td width = \"60\"> <textarea name =\"$kv\" id =\"kv\"></textarea> </td> 
        </tr>           
    </div>
</div>
"; 

}
}
else {      
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgerror')</script>";      
}
}

$kv = 1;
$un = 1;
$i= 1 ;
if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {      

    //$string = "32100";        

    while(isset($_POST[$un])){
        $choix = $_POST["$un"];         

        $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire (Choix)  VALUES('$choix') ";

        $un++;          
        $i++;

        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer);          
    }

    while(isset($_POST[$kv])) {
        $comment = $_POST["$kv"];

        $kv++;
        $enregistrer2 = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('$comment')";         

        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer2);
    }    
}   

?>
```

Comment: What syntax is that mean to be? `INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix)...`  SQL expects a table name there, not some function call or similar.

Comment: Besides: if that code _would_ work it would be side open to sql injection attacks. Please read about the advantages of "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding".

Comment: Your phrasing in the question is extremely vague, it is not clear what you actually try to do and what your actual issue is. Please invest time into phrasing that question in a more precise way. What _exactly_ is it you want to do? What _exactly_ is the issue you ran into? What do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: 1 - my table name is questionnaire  , 2 - values of textarea going in radio button set column  in database named "Choix'' and not in ''Commentara '' the column for Commentary values  and 3 - i m new on php .

Comment: 4- SQL syntax INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: There is a difference between `questionnaire(Choix)` and `questionnaire (Choix)`... The first variant will lead to an error. Which is why I asked you about what you see in your http servers error log file. You _cannot_ program php in a web environment without monitoring that file!

Comment: If you do 2 seperate INSERTS's you will get 2 seperate New Rows, assuming the INSERT does not fail for reasons of not being allowed to strore NULL in one of the columns

Comment: ok edit and indent it for you guys

Comment: Also i give you a link to see my data base [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/240225788715204609/275572723474759680/unknown.png)

Comment: Your code is **not** secure against [*MySQL injections*](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34655/is-there-any-sql-injection-for-this-php-login-example). Use prepared statements available in [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries#t=201701301016270349443) or [MySQLi](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli/11958/prepared-statements-in-mysqli#t=201701301016000852185)

Comment: Sure but before that i need to solve my problem

Comment: It seems that you're aware of the SQL syntax: `INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3....) VALUES (val1, val2, val3....)`. However, in the code, there are multiple SQL statements inserting data in one column at a time. Don't you think this is a problem? It's also very worrying to see `INSERT` statements inside `while` without any terminating condition / logic defined. If you only `echo` your `$enregisterer` and `$enregisterer2` before their respective `mysqli_query()`, you'll see how and why the code is behaving the way it is.

Comment: Like i said i m new to php and i m here to learn ...

Comment: INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('3') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('2') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('0') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('3')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('2')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('0') I did echo like you said and now i see that the second query isn t working  maybe because i need to put something to say '' there is not anymore radio button selected or values to get then pass to second step insert commentary values '' . I m sorry for my english i m french .

Comment: Any idea of how i could code that part ?